# How to upload a CSV and display with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: angular

So i am currently working on a project with a CSV file upload. I can console.log the csv but it's not UTF-8 encoded. I get the data with the typical **�** symbols in it.

Here is my codeblock:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testing';
  csv = [];


  public changeListener(files: FileList){


    if(files && files.length > 0) {
       let file : File = files.item(0); 
         console.log(file.name);
         //console.log(file.size);
         console.log(file.type);

         let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
         reader.onload = (e) => {
            let csv: string = reader.result as string;
            console.log("\ufeff" + csv);
         }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Problem seems to be in csv file, the code works fine. check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/miscellaneous

Comment: thx but it still displays umlauts (ä,ö,ü..) with � symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it works, i needed to change:

```
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

to

```
reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Everything is ok with the CSV-file it was just a encoding problem - i can now display 'ä,ü,ö...'

Comment: This did the trick for me thank you very much!